# Excel formula to show FORMULA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Ok, guys. I am 100% sure that a few days ago I saw and tested a real built-in Excel formula for showing a formula as text in any cell. Now, when I need it, I cannot find it!!! No VBA, no tricks. Just a simple formula! I think I used it on my home PC, where I have Office 2013. At work I have Office 2010, so I cannot find it. It might be a new feature of Office 2013. The worst thing is that I cannot find it on internet... I saw `SHOWFORMULA()`. Is that a valid formula? Because It does not work for Excel 2010.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122046/excel-getting-formula-of-another-cell-in-a-cell-without-vba

Comment: @Excellll I've found that and I've even used it some time ago. But that's really more difficult than just a sumple `=FORMULATEXT()`. not that difficult, but still, not that simple.

Comment: One of the answers there was `FORMULATEXT`. :-P

Comment: Yep, I read that just before your comment, this is why I already knew about it :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, Excel 2013 has the [`FORMULATEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FORMULATEXT-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8) function which shows the formula as text.

Since Excel 2010 does not have this feature, there are a couple ways you can show formulas without VBA;

1. By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (that's the tilde key
   above the Tab). This one shows all formulas in the sheet.
2. You can place a space it the cell before the `=`. This causes Excel to treat the cell as text.

Comment: You rock, that's awesome! ;)